# Нужно рядом добавить кнопку js

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка, нужно рядом с ним добавить такую же кнопку в таком же стиле, но через js

```
<div class="formButtonGroup-primary">
            

<button type="submit" class="button--primary button button--icon button--icon--reply"><span class="button-text">
                Отправить
            </span></button>
            
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.formButtonGroup-primary')
const originBtn = container.querySelector('button')
const newBnt = originBtn.cloneNode(true)

container.insertBefore(newBnt, originBtn)
```

```html
<div class="formButtonGroup-primary">
            

  <button type="submit" class="button--primary button button--icon button--icon--reply">
    <span class="button-text">
                    Отправить
    </span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('.formButtonGroup-primary').innerHTML += `
  <div class="formButtonGroup-primary">          
    <button type="submit" class="button--primary button button--icon button--icon--reply">
      <span class="button-text">Отправить</span>
    </button>           
  </div>
`
```

```html
<div class="formButtonGroup-primary">          
  <button type="submit" class="button--primary button button--icon button--icon--reply">
    <span class="button-text">Отправить</span>
  </button>           
</div>
```